# How to use MediaElement in WPF by binding the source to an XPath?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mediaelement

I'm trying to use the standard WPF MediaElement to play a file(s) from a path that is provided by a XML data source.

So, the XML element looks like:

```
<Video Path="MediaFiles/Videos/video1.mp4" />
```

I'm using a simple DataTemplate to show the video:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Imagetemplate">
    <MediaElement Source="{Binding XPath=@Path}" Width="50" Height="100"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Before I can compile, I'm already receiving an error by IntelliSense on the MediaElement:

```
Error       Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and the rebuilding solution?

Comment: Not just this! I also get this after PC restart...